# Multi-dimension array allocation for class variable

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I am trying to use c++11 for multi dimension array allocation in class variable. it is not possible to use "float **a=new float[][]", trying to use auto, but still not working. Any idea working around, Gentleman!

```
#include <string.h>
class abc{
 public:
 float **a;
 abc(){
   auto a=new float[10][10];
   this->a=a;
 }
};
int main(){
 abc * a=new abc();
 return 1;
}
```

here is the error result: 
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d69bcd38f4bbf2a

Comment: **Please don't. Just don't.** Use an `std::array` or an `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I am not a professional, just working on some simple codes. in fortran, it can be done with allocate(a(n,n,n,n)). seems c and c++ need more codes for this point.

Comment: If you are not a professional, then it's probably the best reason **not to use `new`.** `std::array` and `std::vector` are easier to use and safer. In order to use `new` correctly, you need quite a bit of C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What you allocate is an array of arrays. You cannot assign that to a pointer to pointers, because you don't have an array of pointers, but of other arrays. And arrays aren't pointers. They can decay to ones, but that's a different story.

Declare `a` as

```
float (*a)[10];
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb7cceb405d4ed1f).

Comment: Thanks, Columbo. But in some cases, it will be more favourable  to relax all the dimensions.

Comment: @YunguiXu If you don't know the bounds at compile time, a simple array will presumably not work anyway.

Comment: @YunguiXu To expand on Columbo's comment: in order to allocate an array or index into it, the compiler needs to know the size of each element of the array.  `float[]` is an incomplete type, and its size is not known to the compiler, so you cannot declare or allocate an array of `float[]`.  The declaration `float (*a)[];` is in fact legal, but you can't use it as an array, and there's no way you can initialize it with a `new`.  (You can initialize it with something like `extern float v[]; float (*a)[] = v;`.)